# C# ShellStream disposed after certain replies by Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssh

I created my own terminal that does SSH communication (renci.sshnet / C#). I've recently ran into an issue specific to Ubuntu SSH.

**Problem:**

Some commands such as 'cd' work fine. Other commands like 'ls' will get a proper reply, but the Shellstream object becomes disposed afterwards. Can you point me in the right direction on why this is happening?

**Troubleshooting:**

- When I use Moba, I do not get the problematic behavior.
- Tested w/ Openwrt qsdk (Different Linux), works perfectly
- The last two (2) characters received are 13,10 (\r\n)
- I've launched a shell script (test.sh) which does 'cd' still same behavior.
- Created error event handlers, which do not trigger.
- Tried to use wireshark, but do not know enough about it to troubleshoot. Just saw a lot of encrypted messages.
- Removed all ShellStream Read functions, and it still disposes the Shellstream after the first 'ls' command.
- when I issue the command stty -echo, it seems to fix the situation. Not sure why. stty -echo basically just makes it so Linux doesn't echo back the commands you type.

[image]
**Create SSH client and Shell Stream**

```
        private void ConnectSSH()
        {
            if (m_strAddr == "")
            {
                LaunchSSHInfoForm();
                return;
            }

            m_Client = new SshClient(m_strAddr, m_strUser, m_strPW);

            try
            {
                m_Client.Connect();
                m_Output = m_Client.CreateShellStream("Terminal", 1, 1, 50, 50, 100);
            .......
```

**Send String**

```
            if (m_Client != null && m_Client.IsConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    m_Output.WriteLine(m_strInput.Text);
                    m_RtbParser.AddStringToQueue(m_strInput.Text, Colors.LightCoral);
                    m_strInput.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", ex);
                }
            }
```

**Read String**

```
            if (m_Client != null && m_Client.IsConnected)
                strMessage = m_Output.Read();
```

Thanks and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I think I found the answer and I want to share.

So, If you notice the screenshot in the question shows all the directories in 1 column.

I upped the column count from 1 to 0, and now the terminal displays data more comparable to what you would see in the actual linux terminal, and more importantly, it doesn't dispose the ShellStream.

```
m_Output = m_Client.CreateShellStream("Terminal", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000);
```

[image]